# Simple Java webapp to create/read/update/delete rows in database

Tags: open-source, web-apps, database-browser

I have a SQL database containing tables like "Employees", "Clients", etc.

I want to quickly create a web interface to allow office workers to easily add new Employees, new Clients, edit them, etc.

Requirements:

- Users can only create/read/update/delete, they can not create a new table or drop an entire database, not run arbitrary SQL commands
- Intuitive user interface, for users who have no idea what databases are. So not something that looks like PhpMyAdmin.
- Fields are read dynamically from tables definition. For instance, if I add a column "Phone" to the table "Clients", then the web interface will start showing this new field, without having to change any setting or re-compile anything
- Lists are sortable, for instance I can sort Employees by name
- Open source
- Self-hosted, runnable in Tomcat or any other app server as a .war
- Can run in a local network, no need to access the Internet
- Compatible with at least PostGreSQL, ideally any SQL-compliant server
- Lightweight

Bonus for:

- Ability via settings to mark a column as hidden, so that users do not see it.
- Build intelligent user interface for foreign keys, for instance when creating a new Employee, let the user select another Employee as the value of the field "manager"
- Show constraints in the user interface, for instance to show that "name" is required when creating a new "Employee"